# How to skip validations when using the `validate` method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, skip

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9. I implemented a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators) and I would like to skip validations (on creating a new object in a migration file) when using the `validate` method. In general I can use [`:without_protection => true`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes) as a parameter of the `create!` method but in my case (see the code below) it seems do not work: validation are not skipped.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate do
    # custom validation code
  end
end
```

How can I skip validations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to ensure that all of the other validations are disabled in order for this to be effective. ActiveRecord cannot selectively disable validations, but can omit them entirely.

For instance:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :something,
    :if => :validations_are_turned_on?

  validate :always

protected
  def validations_are_turned_on?
    !@validations_disabled
  end
end
```

Tagging any of the non-essential validations with the appropriate `:if` condition should work. In this case if `@validations_disabled` is not set then all validations will run.

Comment: In my case (when using the `validate do ... end` *block*) is there someway to avoid to state the method name (as you made with `:something`) and to apply the `:if` condition to the "validation block"?

Comment: You can always declare your validation in-line using the block-driven approach, but it does tend to add clutter in my opinion. Whatever works for you, though.

Answer (score 1):

Without protection **does not** turn off validations, it allows you to mass-assign protected attributes. To save without validating:

```
new_record = Article.new
new_record.save(:validate => false)
```